# Android. How can I test a method which uses an Intent over the activity Context

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-intent

After three days trying to find this over this website and others, I really need your help.

I want to test a method in a class. This method uses the activity class context to call an intent. 
When I call it from the test method i get a NullPointerException. 
How can i do this? (add example code please).

Accesories is the ActivityClass.

The Method in the Docking class:

```
public boolean powerConnected() {

    boolean res = false;
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Context cont = Accessories.context;
    Intent intent = cont.registerReceiver(null, filter); --Throws the exception
    int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    if(plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC){
        Log.d(TAG, "AC "+plugged);
        res = true;
    }else if (plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB){
        Log.d(TAG, "USB "+plugged);
        res = false;
    }
    return res;
}
```

The testing Method:

```
@Test
public void testPowerConnected_AssertParamConnected_ReturnTrue() {
    Docking docking = new Docking();
    boolean result = docking.powerConnected();
    assertTrue(result);
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: What is Accessories ? a custom class ?

Comment: Accesories is just the a custom class which extends Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution.

If the TestClass extends AndroidTestCase and not ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 as I had, 
there is a protected mContext in the AndroidTestCase that stores the context as a field.

After that, the only I have to do is pass this context to my method to test.

so the final code will be just this:

```
@Test
public void testPowerConnected_AssertParamA1Connected_ReturnTrue() {
    Docking docking = new Docking();
    //MockContext context = new CustomMock();
    boolean result = docking.powerConnected(mContext);
    assertTrue("Expected true and get "+result,result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could refractor your code to give the context as a parameter to your method:

```
public boolean powerConnected(Context cont) {
   ....
}
```

so that when you call it with your test, you can use a [MockContext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContext.html)

```
class CustomMock extends MockContext {
  Intent registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
    // You can return a MockIntent based on your testing needs.
  }
}

@Test
public void testPowerConnected_AssertParamConnected_ReturnTrue() {
  Docking docking = new Docking();
  MockContext cont = new CustomMock ();

  boolean result = docking.powerConnected(cont);
  assertTrue(result);
}
```

Comment: Mmmm why do I need a mockIntent if what I'm going to pass to the docking.powerConnected is a context?
How can I create the MockContext from the Activity Context?
I tried using createPackageContext(String packageName, int flags) but doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I understand now what are you doing there. But the intent is not exactly the same than the normal Intent? 
What should I write in the Mock Intent for the porpuse of my method?
I want to test if the device is connected to th AC adapter or not.
I don't understand well how this works...

Comment: I will give you points on this answer because you point me in the right direction refactoring the mehtod and giving the context as parameter. 
Thank you.

Comment: Ah ok ! I did not know exactly how to test for Android, I just knew it existed. Your solution is much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making the powerConnected() function static? Then there would be no need for the

```
Docking docking = new Docking()
```

which I imagine is causing your problems....if it isn't then I recommend posting the LogCat output.

Comment: Cannot make this, What is causing my problems is 
 `Intent intent = cont.registerReceiver(null, filter);`
because needs the context of the activity. 
The logcat says as I said: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.accesory_qts.Docking.powerConnected(Docking.java:64)
com.example.accesory_qts.test.DockingATest.testPowerConnected_AssertParamConnected_ReturnTrue(DockingATest.java:247)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
...

Answer (score 0):

If `Docking` is a subclass of `Activity`, you cannot do this:

```
Docking docking = new Docking();
```

Only the Android framework can instantiate Android components (Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, ContentProvider), because it doesn't just call the constructors, it also sets up the appropriate `Context`.

You can only test a method of the activity, if it is being called within the context of that activity. This means that you need to actually have Android create the activity first and then you can test methods within that activity.

Your other option is to change the method so that it uses the Application context using `getApplicationContext()` instead of the activity context. In that case you wouldn't have to create an instance of the activity just to call this method.

Comment: Docking is not a subclass of Activity. 
I found the solution. Thank you.